# How to pass data from UITableView to UIViewController without segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass the title of Row in `UITableView` to my `ViewController`. I don't have VC in storyboard (I've created it by code). So I can't use segue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    cell.textLabel?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        var titleOfFood = String()
        if searching == true {
           titleOfFood = searchedFoods[indexPath.row].title
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
             print(titleOfFood)
        } else {
            titleOfFood = foods[indexPath.row].title
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
             print(titleOfFood)
        }

    let controller = EatenFoodViewController()
    let transitionDelegate = SPStorkTransitioningDelegate()
    controller.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    //controller.delegate = self
    transitionDelegate.customHeight = 620
    transitionDelegate.showIndicator = false
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I need to pass `titleOfFood` to `EatenFoodViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a segue to send data to the destination vc , you can simply do

```
controller.titleOfFood = arr[indexPath.row].title // assuming you have an array of models
```

**OR**

```
controller.titleOfFood = cell.textLabel!.text!
```

---

```
class EatenFoodViewController:UIViewController {
   var titleOfFood = ""
}
```

Comment: How to send to titleOfFood row the title of row from UITableView and I can't understand var titleOfFood = "". What is this. And what to do with this :)

Comment: see edit `var titleOfFood = ""` is the variable supposed to receive the send value and you should use it anyhow inside your destination vc